# White Space occur only in mobile view because of scroll up icon

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a website using a free template [Click here to go on the website](https://demo.w3layouts.com/demos_new/template_demo/15-03-2018/digital_biz-demo_Free/1108230677/web/index.html)

When you scroll up after scroll down you will notice a red standing arrow at the bottom right corner this is an image of the red arrow on which if you hit it will scroll the page to top #Home.

Now the problem is on my laptop it looks ok but when I do inspect to see mobile view then I can notice a white space created by this feature.

this is the image :
[Click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKAVy.jpg)

I already tried using :

```css
html,body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
```

and notice that only overflow-x: hidden remove white space but also affect then arrow scroll functionality and also still little bit space persist towards right size with a bottom scrollbar. 
I tried to remove the entire scroll code also but still unable to remove this white space which is occurring only in mobile view.

I gave a link to the entire website instead of mentioning here as I don't know which code is causing a problem and can't provide a code of entire website at here.
Please see the link and over there you will find the entire website with this scrolling feature on each page. Thanks

Comment: i think it should be a fixed one, i dont think there should be a problem, i am not seeing much white space there in mobile view

Comment: I found the problem, how can I show you the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The image used as the background of your `#toTop` element is 32px wide, so change the width:

```
#toTop {
    width: 32px;
}
```

If you need to push it away from the right hand side, use a `margin-right`.

Comment: On reducing the width to 32px from existing it is rather causing the vertical arrow to move more towards the right and when I am trying margin-right as you mention on the <a> tag then one is moving towards the left which but still white space persist.